# CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx exiring after only a few hours: exit code 2

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, certificate

I followed the steps to get a new one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230260(v=vs.110).aspx) but continued to get the same errors described below.  What works is to make a new key, move it to bld\Debug\platforms\windows8 and rename it to match the name of the certificate already there named `CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx`.  Only then am I able to debug.  So I thought all was fine and dandy but then only a few hours later I get the same errors and have to make a new certificate again.  So this time I make sure that the expiration date is set to next year, but alas, it too expires after only a few hours and I get the same errors below all over again.  I can certainly keep making new certificates and renaming them over and over again but it seems like there's probably something causing it to expire so quickly, any thoughts?  This has happened several times now so either something is very off with my environment or I'm missing something here.

`Error  3   C:\path\to\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2   C:\path\to\EXEC
Warning 1   The certificate specified has expired. For more information about renewing certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478. [C:\path\to\CordovaApp.jsproj]  C:\path\to\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets
Error   2   The certificate specified has expired. For more information about renewing certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478. [C:\path\to\CordovaApp.jsproj]  C:\path\to\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets
Error   4   The command ""C:\path\to\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows-x64" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "ohdh" --language "en-US" "--x64"" exited with code 8. C:\path\to\Microsoft.MDA.targets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, see http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/11/11/cordova-certificate-issue-were-working-on-it/ for details and workarounds.